# How was the space station fly-through in 2001: A Space Odyssey filmed?

Tags: effects, stanley-kubrick, 2001-a-space-odyssey

In the sequence set to the Blue Danube Waltz, we see a Pan Am orbital shuttle docking with a partially-completed space station.  [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3oHmVhviO8) is a clip from that sequence on YouTube.  There are good views of the space station at 0:02-0:28 and 1:28-1:46 in that clip that keep the camera at a respectful distance, as would be expected given late 1960s technology:  models (since no CGI yet) and large cameras guided on rails (no motion control, either).  But the final shot (1:56-2:17) has the camera viewpoint go through the structure of the space station!  How was this accomplished?  Was the model the size of a house, or did Kubrick have something else up his sleeve?

Comment: They had an early form of motion control - rigs utilizing the selsyn motor to synchronize the shots, and then repeat (lots of) them without jiggling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At first I thought it might have been a breakaway model, used by the likes of Orsen Welles to make a camera appear to pass through a neon sign or window in Citizen Kane, but then I watched the clip and realized this could not be the case.

I have had some experience with motion control cameras, and this certainly seems to have been produced using a track system and large model. Some further digging [revealed](http://www.starshipmodeler.com/2001/2001ref.htm) that the studio model was approximately 8 feet in diameter, which accounts for the astonishing level of detail and the fact that a camera can pass right through it.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the link.  I thought that an 8-foot model would have been too tight a fit for a 65mm Panavision camera, but I've just found out that their first "hand held" model (24 lbs!) was [released in 1960](http://www.widescreenmuseum.com/widescreen/panavisn.htm); perhaps that was what was used.